# Sync file permissions *only*

Tags: file-permissions, rsync, chmod, chown

A junior team member did a nasty `chmod -R 777` in `/etc/` and cause SSH cannot login remotely in a Ubuntu server. Now I fixed this login issue by manually set the correct file permissions on `/etc/ssh/*`, `/etc/sudoers`, `/etc/ssl/*` by comparing other normal system. But there are so many other files which may cause future issues.

I am thinking to use rsync to do the work, but don't want it to sync file contents, just permissions, no more work.

Is that possible? I see rsync has `-a` option but it does too much.

Comment: What you are asking is possible, but not with rsync, I'm afraid.

Comment: Thank you for replying, so what's that? I am open for other tools.

Comment: Well, you can write a script to read the attributes of files on one system and set the attributes on the other. Nothing magical.

Comment: http://samba.2283325.n4.nabble.com/Using-rsync-to-just-resync-permissions-and-ownership-td4648100.html

Comment: Also see [fixunix.com](http://fixunix.com/unix/88355-rsync-permissions-*only*.html) for a discussion developing a shell script that applies permissions of a set of files to their copies

Comment: You might have better luck with the Unix & Linux community

Answer (score 19):

If you have the "normal" content of /etc available on the same system (like mounted in some other directory, let's say `/mnt/correct/etc`), you could use the `--reference` parameter to `chmod` and `chown` commands, and combine it with `find` that is started from the "normal" directory:

```
$ cd /mnt/correct/etc
$ find . ! -type l -exec chown -v --reference='{}' /etc/'{}' \;
$ find . ! -type l -exec chmod -v --reference='{}' /etc/'{}' \;
```

(I'm assuming you're on a UNIX system with GNU coreutils versions of chmod and chown.)

The `"! -type l"` condition in `find` excludes symbolic links, because otherwise `chmod` will use the link's permissions to change the file the link points to (and same applies to `chown`).

Comment: This works very well but I just wanted to point out that you should `chown` _before_ doing the `chmod` because chown will clear setuid/setgid bits.

Answer (score 1):

Please note you can also try something that won't necessarily make you need to copy files from one place to another (depending on the filesize it may be desired)

You could use a mix of find and some grepping to generate a shell script to be executed on the host where you need to fix permissions.. you could use the same approach to generate a script for changing users/groups as well.. for example:

```
# find . -printf 'chmod %m %p #%M\n' | sort -k3 | grep -Pi '\s+\S*s\S*$'  > /var/tmp/fix_permissions.bash 
# bash /var/tmp/fix_permissions.bash
```

In the example above, what it does is to list all the files with their attributes in this format:

```
chmod 2755 ./addfs_7.1.0/bin #drwxr-sr-x
chmod 2755 ./addfs_7.1.0/config #drwxr-sr-x
chmod 2755 ./addfs_7.1.0 #drwxr-sr-x
chmod 2755 ./addfs_7.1.0/install #drwxr-sr-x
chmod 2755 ./addfs_7.1.0/library.dda #drwxr-sr-x
chmod 2755 ./addfs_7.1.0/library #drwxr-sr-x
chmod 2755 ./autosimimport #drwxr-sr-x
```

And in my case I only want to sync those with the 's' flag, so I filter with `grep -Pi '\s+\S*s\S*$'`. Sort was there as well because I had to compare the files in the other host.

**TLDR**

If you just want to apply all the permissions with no filtering or comparing:

1. Create a script with the correct permissions on the "base" host

   `find . -printf 'chmod %m %p\n' > /var/tmp/fix_permissions.sh`
2. Execute the script in the other host

   `bash /var/tmp/fix_permissions.sh`

Comment: This was helpful when I didn't have rights to NFS mount between the systems to use `chmod --reference`, thanks! I'm a little surprised rsync doesn't have this ability itself.

Comment: this is a good idea, but misses some corner cases like chmod of a symbolic link and file names with spaces in them.

Comment: @JosephTingiris, granted! hopefully the approach can be tuned to more specific use cases like using some quote escaping within the printf command for file names with spaces: `find . -printf "chmod %m '%p'\n" > /var/tmp/fix_permissions.sh`.. as for symbolic links, hopefully some tuning of the find parameters can provide the desired results